# Delete all cells in a sheet based on interior color

Tags: excel, vba

```
Range("A:A").Select
For Each Cell In Selection
    If ActiveCell.Interior.Color = Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbOrange Then
        cell.clear
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Avoid a slow loop. Use 'Find' with a search on 'Format'

Answer (score 1):

This should work better (in your code you were always checking the active cell):

```
Range("A:A").Select
For Each Cell In Selection
    If cell.Interior.Color = Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbOrange Then
        cell.clear
    End If
Next
```

And you don't need to select the range so you could also write:

```
For Each Cell In Range("A:A")
    If cell.Interior.Color = Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbOrange Then
        cell.clear
    End If
Next
```

Comment: What i have setup is a conditional format to fill certain duplicate cells with a color and then delete them with this code but its still not working

Comment: Maybe you need to remove the conditional formatting first using `cell.FormatConditions.Delete`?

Comment: well see i figured its still fill color there for it should work.

Comment: ok well im really new at this if my original thoughts wont work can i get help as to where i should start over again at? so first ti would be find duplicates and delete them . seeing as thats a function already in excel which i cannot get to work.

  Range("A:Y").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("A:Y").RemoveDuplicates column 1

Answer (score 1):

This code uses `Find` to quickly clear cells matching your desired format

The line to update for other cell fromats is:
`.FindFormat.Interior.Color = Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbOrange`

```
Option Explicit
Sub FastFind()
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim cel1 As Range
    Dim strFirstAddress As String
    Dim lAppCalc As Long

    'Get working range from user
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng1 = Application.InputBox("Please select range to search for ", "User range selection", Selection.Address(0, 0), , , , , 8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If rng1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    With Application
        lAppCalc = .Calculation
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .FindFormat.Interior.Color = Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbOrange
    End With

    Set cel1 = rng1.Find("", , xlValues, xlPart, xlByRows, , , , True)
    If Not cel1 Is Nothing Then
        Set rng2 = cel1
        strFirstAddress = cel1.Address
        Do
            Set cel1 = rng1.Find("", cel1, xlValues, xlPart, xlByRows, , , , True)
            Set rng2 = Union(rng2, cel1)
        Loop While strFirstAddress <> cel1.Address
    End If

    If Not rng2 Is Nothing Then rng2.Clear

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = lAppCalc
    End With
End Sub
```